# Generic overflow detection in C++ types

Tags: c++, types, overflow, gnu

I want to have a generic method that can detect overflows in all types such as char, unsigned char, short, unsigned short, int32, unsigned int32, long, unsigned long, int64, unsigned int64 etc

On later C++ we can use `__builtin_add_overflow_p` to detect the overflow on addition. The macro can be like this

```
#define ADD_OVERFLOW(a, b)  __builtin_add_overflow_p (a, b, (__typeof__ ((a) + (b))) 0)
```

The issue is this will not detect overflow in 8bit or 16bit types such as char or short. Need a generic and efficient mechanism to detect the overflow. Efficient means fewer cpu cycles as possible because the check need to be put in many places. Inefficient check can slow down the program. Therefore **Efficiency is a must**

I tried this also

```
#define ADD_OVERFLOW(a, b) ((__typeof__(a))(a + b) < a)
```

It did not work for some signed types eg, int32
Is there a generic solution that works for all types in C++?

Comment: You say "[o]n later C++ we can use `__builtin_add_overflow_p` to detect the overflow". This is incorrect. There's no `__builtin_add_overflow_p` function in standard C++. It's an extension of a specific compiler.

Comment: Convert to type large enough to hold any result (for types smaller than `int` use `int`).  Do the arithmetic operation.  Test the result for overflow of the original type.  Profile the application to see how efficient this is.  I would write a template class to do all of the above.

Comment: Testing for overflow after the (signed) addition is already too late, as UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__builtin_add_overflow_p` *does* work with 8 and 16 bit types. The problem is that `(__typeof__ ((a) + (b)))` is `int`, and it doesn't overflow in `int`.

What you probably want is for `a` and `b` to be the same type and to check if the addition overflows in that type:

```cpp
template<typename T>
constexpr bool add_overflow(T a, T b) {
    return __builtin_add_overflow_p(a, b, T{0});
}

static_assert(add_overflow((signed char) 125, (signed char) 100));
static_assert(!add_overflow((signed char) 125, (signed char) -3));

// Or if you *must* use a macro:
#define ADD_OVERFLOW(a, b) __builtin_add_overflow_p(a, b, \
    std::enable_if_t< \
        std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<decltype(a)>, std::decay_t<decltype(b)>>, \
        std::decay_t<decltype(a)>>{0})
```